# How My elite proxy is detected with browser but not with proxifier

Tags: networking, proxy

I am wonder that how elite proxy works because I use several browser for elite proxies that show my real ip address. However I use a software like proxifier with the same proxy and doesn't show my real ip address.

My question is, Why whenever I use browser my ip address shown but with proxifier no! Is there anyway to fix the problem?

**Proxifier**: https://www.proxifier.com

**ProxyTester**: http://amibehindaproxy.com/

Header for Browser: (For security reason I change my ip to xx.xx.xx.xx in below text)

```
HTTP_HOST: amibehindaproxy.com
HTTP_USER_AGENT: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:37.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/37.0
HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING: gzip, deflate
HTTP_CONNECTION: close
REQUEST_METHOD: GET
SERVER_PROTOCOL: HTTP/1.1
SERVER_PORT: 80
HTTP_X_FORWARED_FOR: xx.xx.xx.xx, 186.209.74.112
HTTP_VIA: 1.1 186.209.75.33 (Mikrotik HttpProxy)
```

header for proxifier:

```
HTTP_HOST: amibehindaproxy.com
HTTP_USER_AGENT: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:37.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/37.0
HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING: gzip, deflate
HTTP_CONNECTION: close
REQUEST_METHOD: GET
SERVER_PROTOCOL: HTTP/1.1
SERVER_PORT: 80
HTTP_X_FORWARED_FOR: 186.209.74.112
HTTP_VIA: not set
```

Comment: Some browsers are 'proxy-aware'  and can /will traverse the proxy..

Comment: Do you know web-browser C#.net is proxy-aware or not? And Why don't you send more details about it as answer that can be accept it?

Comment: Many Sites will use Java and or Flash to identify IP.  A proxy will not obscure this traffic. You will have to disable these applications to keep them from leaking your IP.

Comment: Forgot that too....VERY good point @Tom Ruh

Comment: Does elite proxies included ip addresses in header packets?

Comment: Or you mean web-browser doesn't apply proxy setting to such the protocols on websites?